# How to get in touch with World of Warcraft narrative without playing the game?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I like the Warcraft lore. I enjoyed Warcraft 3 immensly, even played a bit of WoW a long time ago. From time to time Blizzard gives us a new cinematic trailer, like they recently did, and something stirrs within me to find out what is going on there.

However, I hate MMOs grinding that's a neccessary part of the experience. Is there a way to keep up with the lore without actually playing the game? Some extracted form of the narrative, describing the key world-changing events?

I know of [the Wiki](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/Portal:Main) and it mostly contains what I'd like to know, for example I enjoyed how they briefly (maybe a bit too briefly) described everything Burning Legion was up to - however the information is fragmented into small unconnected chunks, and with recent time travel shenanigans I don't even know what I need to search for.

Comment: Wow actually has not a whole lot of grinding, especially if you avoid the gear threadmill. you can do quests up to max level, and aside from a few mythic-only bosses, all the lore is available, even at the lowest difficulty. and aside from the old zones from before the Cataclysm, most of it is still available.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Unless something serious happened to the game since Burning Crusade times even simply doing quests is grinding when half of them is just killing enough enemies or looting something from their corpses. And it took me 1 month to get to level 70. I can't imagine what level 100 would require...

Comment: if you buy the game up to the current expansion (which is Warlords of Draenor), you can upgrade your character to level 90 for free so you can jump right in. Also, questing has improved A LOT since TBC. WotLK has still it's share of old style questing, but it does a far better job at streamlining the questing experience. They also fixed the quest RNG, which makes quest items drop far more predictably, and most quests ask you to kill stuff in a certain location, not mobs of a certain name.

Comment: @Deltharis: The very next expansion substantially improved matters, and the expansion after that brought the changes back to 1-60. The Burning Crusade is far more painful to play through than any of the rest.

Comment: The quests really have gotten a lot better. I don't really feel like it's a grind anymore, until the fifth or sixth alt...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of options you have for checking out the Warcraft lore.

As sommerjj says, **you have [Nobbel87's youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6037698E84060287).**

**You also have the various wiki sites,** which host a large collection of information regarding Warcraft. I find the most notable to be the [WoWWiki](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6037698E84060287), which has an extensive library of articles surrounding the history, events, and characters of Warcraft.

**[Blizzard have a section on their website](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/game/lore/)**, where they post short stories and comics. This can be considered a valuable resource, given it originates from the official creators.

If you like reading, **there is also an extensive series of novels** set in the Warcraft universe. [The WoWWiki has a good list of them, here](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Novels). Many concern major events, while others tell unrelated stories that may tie in to the general lore.

Lastly, **it may be worth looking up the cinematic trailers surrounding World of Warcraft**. While short, they tease various upcoming releases (notably the release of a new expansion, or a new major content patch), and often show off a massive event in a well put together animated short.

**You do have the option to play World of Warcraft**, of course, which you have already told us you don't particularly want to do. It is worth pointing out that Wrath of the Lich King moved a fair bit away from the stigma of grind and monotony, while Cataclysm brought an entire rewrite of most of the vanilla world, bringing over with it the dynamic changes made from Wrath of the Lich King. If this is still not an option for you, it may be worth looking up the various instances and raids, as these often represented major events during the course of the game.

Comment: +1 for the novels. They're great if you're into fantasy books. It's also worth noting that there is WoW [Comics](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Comics) and [Manga](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Manga) out there.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest checking out [Nobbel87's](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6037698E84060287) channel on YouTube.  He does indepth lore videos on the characters and settings.  He's been doing videos on the patches for a while now.  I'd start with those and then delve into individual characters.